# Get list of tuples of stacked for loop values

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

While trying to speed up:

```
l = some_value
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        for k in range(1000):
            function(i, j, k, l)
```

I stumbled upon `multiprocessing.Pool().starmap()` however it requires the iterated values to be passed in as an interator `[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), ...]`. Is there a fast way to get this list of tuples containing the for loop values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iterator you need:

```
iterator = ((i, j, k, l) for i in range(1000) 
                         for j in range(1000) 
                         for k in range(1000))
```

Comment: It returns a generator object, but may I ask, why use a generator?

Comment: The generator behaves like an iterator and creates needed values lazily, i.e. when they are asked for instead of creating a list of 1000x1000x1000 values in memory.